# How do I create a 3d chart in Excel where three columns represent the three axes?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, charts

I have a data series of three columns where each column represents an axis. For example:

```
X  | Y  | Z
   |    |
-1 | -1 | 5
-1 |  0 | 4.9
-1 |  1 | 5.1
 0 | -1 | 4.8
 0 |  0 | 5 
 0 |  1 | 5.2
```

etc.

How do I get Excel to recognize that these are three separate axes? Specifically, I'm using Excel 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Following the directions given here should do it:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-the-display-of-a-3-D-chart-60C13909-D2A1-4E06-8B8C-BCCBA7868C9B

I've taken the liberty of already setting it to Excel 2010 mode.

TL;DR version: Use the 3d chart tools in the graph ribbon, and it should represent your three axes correctly.

Comment: Unless I'm missing it, that doesn't exactly cover what I'm trying to do.